# Why does passing a static dependency to an useEffect causes it to be called every render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Why does the following useEffect is fired on every render if the dependency never changes?

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log('Here')
}, [['1', '2', '3']]);
```

Comment: On every render that static array has a new reference, technically it's a new array. That's why it's rendering again your component. Exactly the same reason why `[1,2,3] === [1,2,3]` is `false`.

Comment: But in my understanding useEffect checked against value changes and not changes to reference or is this wrong?

Comment: useeffect is called every once  when component. mount. when you add data in the array it allow to re render whenever that variable hold data or data changes. so in this case, it is called once, then when you fired set state, that time again this is called because array is same, and you're not implemented any condition inside useeffect to never rerender once data changed and condition satisfy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Each item* of dependency array is checked using strict equality. That means it uses the `===` operator.

So it checks if `oldDeps[0] === newDeps[0]` and then checks `oldDeps[1] === newDeps[1]`, and so on. It will execute the effect if any of those checks are false.

Lastly, two arrays with the items are not strictly equal:

```
[1,2,3] === [1,2,3] // false

const a = [1,2,3]
const b = a
a === b // true
```

This is because they are two different arrays, they just happen to contain the same content. But in the above code, `a === b` is true because both variables reference the same array.

---

Typically, you do not want to construct an array as one of a hooks dependencies for this reason. If you have a list of id's, you can do things like convert it to a string instead:

```
}, [[1,2,3].join('-')]);
```

This works because strings *are* strictly equal with the same content:

```
"1-2-3" === "1-2-3" // true
```